# Solving SVHN using Tensorflow Error: "Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor.."

Tags: linux, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to solve "SVHN" dataset classification problem using Convolutional Neural Network provided here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks

I read the data and formatted them in this way:

```
read_input = scipy.io.loadmat('data/train_32x32.mat')
converted_label = tf.cast(read_input['y'], tf.int32)
converted_image = tf.cast(read_input['X'], tf.float32)
reshaped_image = tf.transpose(converted_image, [3, 0, 1, 2])
```

In the `_generate_image_and_label_batch` function, I modified the code a little bit as input images in `train_32X32.mat` and `text_32X32.mat` were already in 4D format.

```
images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [image, label],
      batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
      enqueue_many=True,
      num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
      capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * FLAGS.batch_size,
      min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
```

I ended up with these errors:

```
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 4
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 4
W tensorflow/core/kernels/cast_op.cc:66] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shapedim { size: 32 } dim { size: 32 } dim { size: 3 } dim { size: 73257 }
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7f1c180015a0 Compute status: Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shapedim { size: 32 } dim { size: 32 } dim { size: 3 } dim { size: 73257 }
     [[Node: Cast_1 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast_1/x)]]
W tensorflow/core/kernels/cast_op.cc:66] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shapedim { size: 32 } dim { size: 32 } dim { size: 3 } dim { size: 73257 }
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1027] 0x7f1c280ea810 Compute status: Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shapedim { size: 32 } dim { size: 32 } dim { size: 3 } dim { size: 73257 }
     [[Node: Cast_1 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast_1/x)]]
Killed
```

Please let me know if I did any mistake in any logic.

Thanks

Sarah

Comment: How much free memory do you have? The way you are doing it could take 3GB of RAM (you have 1GB of floats to start with, then 1GB comes out of cast, then another 1GB out of transpose)

Comment: I have 3.8 GB total memory but only 1.5 GB free memory. It could be the reason. I will reduce train_32X32.mat in size and then will try again. Thanks a lot @YaroslavBulatov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your data contains 2*32*3*73257 entries, that's 900 MB for float or 1800MB for double. So you have 1800MB allocated at `read_input['X']`, then TF converts it to a tensor to feed into `cast` which is another 900MB. Output of `tf.cast`  is another 900MB tensor, and output of `transpose` is another 900MB tensor.

So you may need 4.5GB of RAM for this to work.

In general this approach (converting to a `Constant` node) is only recommended for "small" problems. There's a hard limit of 2GB you can put into a constant, but even much smaller values (ie >100MB) may cause problems if you ever move to GPU (example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/838))

An alternative, scalable way, is to use an input pipeline like in Cifar example

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. It will be a big help. I will try the pipeline method also as I have plan to work with GPU and very big problems as well.